# How to realize a Generic method of conversion from List<T> to T[]?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I want to realize a generic-based java method to convert a `List<T>` to a `T[]`.

For example, I have a `List<T>`, such as `List<Double>`:

```
List<Double> lst = Arrays.asList( new Double[]{1.11, 2.22, 3.33} );
```

And I have following method:

```
public static <T> T[] listToArray(List<T> inputList)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> type = (Class<T>)NumberTypeOfString(inputList.get(0).toString());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] resultArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, inputList.size());

    for(int i=0; i < inputList.size(); i++)
    {
        resultArray[i] = (T)inputList.get(i);
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

When I call this method as following:

```
Double[] resultArray = listToArray(lst);
```

I get an exception that I really can't understand:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String
```

Why does that happen?

PS: method "NumberTypeOfString" above is to input a String like "1.11" to get a type like Double.class, the same for other numeric type.

EDIT:

I will delete the second question ( "is there any way to realize the method correctly?") for more attention on this code.

**SOLUTION & DEEP QUSTION:**

```
Just use List<Double> and nothing goes wrong at all.
```

But, in fact, I have a method to generate AP or GP which returns an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayOfResult = createArrayOfProgression("ratio; 1; 2; 12;12");
```

in which, "ratio; 1; 2; 12;12" means choice; first; step; last; total number.

The content of arrayOfResult is:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0, 32.0, 64.0, 128.0, 256.0, 512.0, 1024.0, 2048.0]
```

The result for calling this is an ArrayList but caused the above exception when this arrayOfResult is later inputted into listToArray.
Here is the code:

```
    public enum caculator{
    diff, ratio;
}

public static <T> ArrayList<T> createArrayOfProgression(String firstStepLastTotal)
{
    String[] arrayOfParameter = firstStepLastTotal.replace(" ", "").split(";");
    String choice = arrayOfParameter[0];

    double first = Double.valueOf(arrayOfParameter[1]);
    double step = Double.valueOf(arrayOfParameter[2]);
    String strlast = arrayOfParameter[3];
    String strtotal = "";
    if(arrayOfParameter.length == 5)
    {
        strtotal = arrayOfParameter[4];
    }
    else
    {
        strtotal = "";
    }

    Class<?> classOfNumber = NumberTypeOfString(arrayOfParameter[2]);

    String strResult = "";
    /**
     * 1. Generate AP or OP by the total number of progression
     */
    if( !strtotal.equals("") && strlast.equals("") )
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Integer.valueOf(strtotal); i++)
        {
            switch(caculator.valueOf(choice))
            {
            case diff:
                strResult += ( first + step * (i) )+ "\n";
                break;
            case ratio:
                strResult += ( first * java.lang.Math.pow(step, (i))) + "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * 2. Generate AP or OP by the last item
     */
    else if( strtotal.equals("") && !strlast.equals("") )
    {
        int locationFirst = 0;
        int locationLast = (int)(Double.valueOf(strlast) -first) / (int)step + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < locationLast - locationFirst; i++)
        {
            switch(caculator.valueOf(choice))
            {
            case diff:
                strResult += ( first + step * (i) )+ "\n";
                break;
            case ratio:
                strResult += ( first * java.lang.Math.pow(step, (i))) + "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * 3. Generate AP or OP by the last item or by the total number of progression
     */
    else if( !strtotal.equals("") && !strlast.equals("") )
    {
        int locationFirst = 0;
        int locationLast = (int)(Double.valueOf(strlast) -first) / (int)step + 1;
        int locationTotal = Integer.valueOf(strtotal);
        for(int i = 0; i < ((locationLast - locationFirst)>locationTotal? (locationLast - locationFirst):locationTotal); i++)
        {
            switch(caculator.valueOf(choice))
            {
            case diff:
                strResult += ( first + step * (i) )+ "\n";
                break;
            case ratio:
                strResult += ( first * java.lang.Math.pow(step, (i))) + "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong!!");
    }
    System.out.println("classOfNumber="+classOfNumber);
    String[] arrayOfResult = strResult.split("\n");

    ArrayList<T> resultList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfResult.length; i++)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T elem = (T) arrayOfResult[i];
        resultList.add( elem );
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

**However,**
I test with following ArrayList and there is no problem:

```
ArrayList<Double> alst = new ArrayList<Double>();
    alst.add(1.11);
    alst.add(2.22);
    alst.add(3.33);
Double[] DresultArray = listToArray(alst);
```

When I use this:

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayOfResult = createArrayOfProgression("diff; 1.11; 1.11; ;3");
//which has the same content: [1.11, 2.22, 3.33], 
Double[] DresultArray = listToArray(arrayOfResult);
```

another exception jumps out:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

I stll don't know the reason why...

Comment: What's wrong with [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]))?

Comment: Note that this method already exists. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])

Comment: Have a look at [java.util.List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29)

Comment: Hi, guys! I think this realization is a checking of my learning of generic, and I write these codes before finding the API, so please check this code, and I also feel grateful for the API hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList() returns an ArrayList which extends AbstractList and NOT ArrayList!` 
hence your exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double`

So incase you are working with `java.util.ArrayList` as Base type and not `java.util.List`, then change your code to the one below.

```
public class G {

public static <T> T[] listToArray(ArrayList<T> inputList)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> type = (Class<T>)inputList.get(0).getClass();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] resultArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, inputList.size());

    for(int i=0; i < inputList.size(); i++)
    {
        resultArray[i] = (T)inputList.get(i);
    }
    return resultArray;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    ArrayList<Double> lst = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( new Double[]{1.11, 2.22, 3.33} ) );
    Double[] d = listToArray( lst );
    System.out.println(d[0]);
}
```

}

Comment: I try to run this: ArrayList<Double> arrayOfResult = createArrayOfProgression("diff; 1.11; 1.11; ;3");
  ArrayList<Double> alst2 = new ArrayList( arrayOfResult ); But still meet an exception: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;, I still thank you for your answer!

Comment: Error Code: `String[] arrayOfResult = strResult.split("\n");` and then you have this ` T elem = (T) arrayOfResult[i];`. Obviously String cannot be cast to Double. Pass the Class<T> as method argument and then use Arrays.newInstance(). It should work fine.

Comment: Thank you!! I find this way of inputing type is a good solution, by using T[] arrayOfResult = (T[]) getNumberArrayFromStringArray(strResult.split("\n")); in which method getNumberArrayFromStringArray() turns Stirng array of numeric format into numeric type array, I finally see no exception at all!!

Comment: You still have to input the exact class of the Number to the method `getNumbere FromArray()`, Like numbers in array can be Double or Long

Comment: You are completely right, I use many regex and if-else to find the numeric type of the array elem and return Class<?> because I don't know the offical package provides simliar function or not.

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
Class<T> type = (Class<T>)NumberTypeOfString(inputList.get(0).toString());
```

To this :

```
Class<T> type = (Class<T>)(inputList.get(0).getClass());
```

From the of `Array.newInstance` doc :

> componentType - the Class object representing the component type of
>   the new array

So the type of the new array needs to be the type of the elements in the `List`.

Comment: I run this new one but get anothor exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;

Comment: Sorry for my fault, I input an ArrayList instead of a List then that happen!! I will change the question to why does an ArrayList cause this. Thnak you!!

Comment: Sincerely thankful! I edit my question again for another related method which generates Arithmetic Progression or Geometric Progression.